# How can I disable Web Inspector for my BlackBerry App?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have developed a Phonegap application for BlackBerry 10. I don't have a real BlackBerry device and I used the BlackBerry simulator the whole time. When I launch the app in the simulator it says Web Inspector Enabled and I am be able connect it through my browser.

Now, I want to release my application but I can't turn this feature off. I have tried building  the application using `phonegap build blackberry --release` but it didn't have any effect. Maybe this message is showing because the device is in development mode and I don't need to do anything? I don't know.

I'd really appreciate some pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the web inspector while releasing into the blackberry store. The web inspector is enabled because you are running the app either through Wi-fi or getting connected with your system.

**And once the app is in stores the web inspector will be disabled**

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make a release build by

cordova build --release blackberry10

or

phonegap build --release blackberry10

Next you can deploy .bar from 
[your project folder ]/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/[name of release bar].bar by

blackberry-deploy -gui

Comment: Alternatively, run `cordova run --device --release --nobuild`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign your app to build it in release mode.  If you do not code sign the app, it will be built in debug mode.

See "Setup for signing" here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html#BlackBerry%2010%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Thanks for this Adam but `cordoca build --release` is not working for some reason. It builds just fine but the app is not in release mode. Also, providing `--keystorepass` is not signing the binary for some reason. If I ditch phonegap (cordova) and use `webworks` binary, however, it builds in release mode and signs the binary just fine.